# Finding and running variables from a class?

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm using jquery for my site, I have a list of variables that need to be called once a button is pressed. Basically, I need to determine the variable from the class name! :(

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/f6dLQ/

So it returns the class name of "website", which also is the variable "website" but i need to then somehow determine make it equal the variable not the string "website"?

Please help!

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/f6dLQ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare the variable in the global scope i.e. not in any function, it will be a property of the window object, and can be easily retrieved

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body a').click(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('class');
        alert(window[name]);
    });
});    

var website = "http://journal.shannonhochkins.com/";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f6dLQ/3/

Answer (score 1):

While Musa's solution will work, this seems like poor design. I suggest you make a table mapping class names to data:

```
var class_table = {
  website: "http://journal.shannonhochkins.com/",
  ...
}
```

then use `alert(class_table[name])`

Comment: Why does this actually work? what makes this work if you don't mind me asking? why do you not have to call it a "var" and why does it have to have "window[name]?

Comment: I think your question was about Musa's answer, not mine. The explanation is that all global variables are automatically made properties of the window, and objects in Javascript can be used as associative arrays (e.g. object["foo"] is equivalent to object.foo).